# jquery: get value from nested classes inside a popup/baloon

Tags: jquery, popupwindow

Using Timemap.js I have a trouble to get the string value inside the baloon shown by clicking thje timeline bar.

```
    var compo_tag = $(".compo_tag").find("span").attr("id");
```

[see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQkA2.jpg)

Comment: Nope, from your screen I can see "compo_tag" is under "name" attribute so it should var compo_tag = $("[name='compo_tag']").find("span").attr("id");

Comment: OK . Found the solution
[code]
   $(".leaflet-map-pane").click(function(){
        var compo_tag = $(this).find("span").attr("id");
     });
}); [/code]